# Two characters get spat out every time I get a request

Tags: php, laravel

Really odd stuff here. running Laravel 5.3.0, everything is fine until one day every single request that my application gets, it responds properly but with "re" in front of it. I thought it might have been a typo I put somewhere but can't find it anywhere at all. When I run php artisan it also spits out "re" then lists the available commands. I've tried searching all over the project for where I could have accidentally left it in, but can't seem to find it at all. Any of you guys know what files gets executed before php artisan? It spits out "re" in ajax calls, GET/POST requests, and terminal commands too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yep. Can confirm, had this happen to me too. It's definitely in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug that is not caused by your app. Otherwise why should it show when you type php artisan?

File an issue here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues

Answer (score 0):

I got the same scenario like this before... Try getting a new copy of Laravel. I believe you have somehow edited one of the core files of Laravel and accidentally type 're' without you noticing it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, answering my own question here. it's impossible to do a control find all in a project for a small number of characters, but almost always if it's coming before php artisan or all requests, it's in compile.php before the

hope this helps someone else.